# How to read Custom Property value and term description from NavigationTerm?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, managed-navigation

In publishing sharepoint 2013 site, I am using managed navigation. I need to read value of custom property defined in term store and I also need to read value of description field. Is it possible to do it with read access to site?

I can obtain TaxonomyNavigationContext.Current.NavigationTerm and read basic info. But to read custom property and description, I need to get taxonomy term and I cannot use read-only cached navigation term.

```
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
NavigationTerm navTerm = TaxonomyNavigationContext.Current.NavigationTerm;
Term term = navTerm.GetTaxonomyTerm(session); // I cannot do it due to permission level - user is read only user!
string val = term.CustomProperties["..."]; // this is what I need - read value of custom property - but without need to access Term class.
```

Is there a way how to read custom property from read-only navigation term with user assigned with read permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an account which has the rights to access those terms.
I would go for `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` - however, you'll first need to make sure no "remnants" from the current account are avaiable before accessing the ServiceApplication (TaxonomySession).

So I'd use:

```
var site = ....;
var navTerm = TaxonomyNavigationContext.Current.NavigationTerm;
string prop = null;
using (new CleanHttpContext())
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    using (var elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
    {
        var session = new TaxonomySession(elevatedSite);
        try
        {
            var term = navTerm.GetAsEditable(session).GetTaxonomyTerm(session);
            if (!term.CustomProperties.TryGetValue("...", out prop))
            {
                // no custom property.
                prop = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get the TaxonomyTerm from the NavigationTerm. Are you sure the IIS appPoolUser is also TermStoreAdminstrator?", e);
        }
    }
});
```

in combination with:

```
public class CleanHttpContext : IDisposable
{
    HttpContext oldContext;
    bool isDisposed;

    public CleanHttpContext()
    {
        this.oldContext = HttpContext.Current;
        isDisposed = false;
        HttpContext.Current = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !isDisposed)
        {
            HttpContext.Current = oldContext;
            isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure your IIS AppPool-User is set as TermStoreAdministrator..

Answer (score -1):

surround your code with elevated permissions:

```
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {

                 //Code goes here

            });
```

This works for all authentication types including anonymous users.

Comment: This will never work, `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` does nothing for your TaxonomySession!